# How to prove: If $\left\{a,b\right\}=\left\{c,d\right\}$ then $(a=c\;\;and\;\;b=d)\;\;or\;\;(a=d\;\;and\;\;b=c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am trying to prove this: If $\left\{a,b\right\}=\left\{c,d\right\}$ then $(a=c\;\;and\;\;b=d)\;\;or\;\;(a=d\;\;and\;\;b=c)$

My attempt so far was that if $\left\{a,b\right\}=\left\{c,d\right\}$ then by the definition of equality I get that $a,b\in\left\{c,d\right\}\;\; and\;\; c,d\in\left\{a,b\right\}$. Then I get:

$\Big((a=c \;\;or\;\;a=d)\;\;and\;\;(b=c\;\;or\;\;b=d)\Big)\;\;and\;\;\Big((c=a \;\;or\;\;c=b)\;\;and\;\;(d=a\;\;or\;\;d=b)\Big)$

...?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If $c=d$ then $\{c,d\}=\{c\}$ so equality of the sets tells us that $a=b=c=d$ so result follows.

Similarly for $a=b$.

So we may assume elements are distinct, then you are left with only two cases $a=c$ or $a=d$, and subsequently $b=d$ or $b=c$ (respectively, in that order) so conclusion follows

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $A,B$ two sets. Then, $$A=B\iff (\forall x\in A,\exists y\in B: x=y)\wedge (\forall x\in B, \exists y\in A: x=y).$$